Access Azure Devops OData APIs/endpoints with PAT? (I'm using powershell)
Is there a way to access the Azure DevOps OData feeds using a Personal Access Token (PAT)?
I've tried using the same create-a-PAT-and-base64-encode-it-prepended-with-a-:-and-stuff-it-into-the-authorization-header-as-"Basic $encodedText" process that works for the rest APIs, but that isn't working for the odata endpoints ( I'm trying to use https://analytics.dev.azure.com/org/project/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRuns ).
Is there a way to use a PAT to hit the OData endpoints?
Thank you

The way to call OData queries for Azure DevOps using PAT in PowerShell is same as calling Azure DevOps REST API.
Below is a sample of PowerShell Script as reference.
$organization = "Organization Name"
$project = "Project Name"
$pipelineName = "Pipeline Name"
$uri = "https://analytics.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRuns?`$apply=filter(Pipeline/PipelineName eq '${pipelineName}')/aggregate(`$count as TotalCount, SucceededCount with sum as SucceededCount, FailedCount with sum as FailedCount, PartiallySucceededCount with sum as PartiallySucceededCount, CanceledCount with sum as CanceledCount)"

# Need to convert the PAT to be base64 token for use in the HTTP request headers.
$pat = "Personal Access Token"
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers

# Convert the output as JSON content and print to console.
Write-Host ($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10)
# Save the JSON content of output into a JSON file.
$response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File -FilePath odata-query-output.json



Thank you. It turns out I wasn't properly base64 encoding my $pat
